# How to FIX THIS SPAM AJAX CALL? i want only one show this reuest after click button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

[image: please help me to stop his duplicate response, this my code[][1]]

```
var xhr = $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '<?php echo $action_show_notify?>',//function url.
      cache:true,
      processData:true,
      global:false,
      dataType:"json",
        beforeSend: function()
        {
            $("#open_list").html('<div class="text-center"><img src="<?php echo SITEURL;?>/images/loading.gif" width="30px" height="30px"/></div>');
            $('#callback_list').hide();
        },
        complete: function()
        {
            $("#open_list").fadeOut(200);           
        },
        success: function(data)
        {
            console.log(data);

        }                            
    });
```

thre times this problem`[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]`

but i want this output like this, when i click everytime button
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]

Comment: SPAM? Fix what? You haven't stated what the problem is.

Comment: Do you mean removing the console.log() ???

Comment: after i click button, that request running but every request looping the data , i just want  1 request  after i click the button to show my data

Comment: Nothing in this snippet of code looks "spammy" to me. The code *calling* this code is likely the culprit.

Comment: Can you post the full click handler code?

Comment: Probably something like trying to loop over some form data, but doing a POST every iteration instead. We need the code calling this function.

Comment: thre times object show after i clicked three, and i just want one object show. when i click everytime that button